# How to make dropdown menu with tag a?

Tags: html, css

How can I make a dropdown menu with tag `<a>` instead of button?

I tried with button tag but it kinda mess with my layout. I want to do it with `<a>` tag but the dropdown box went over the text which makes it go missing instead of being under the text.

It's hard to explain here but you can see in more detail below

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 24px;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
}

nav a {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 430;
  color: lightgrey;
}

nav a.active {
  color: #d4af37;
}

nav a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: white;
}

nav.scroll {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 430;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <div style="padding-left:105px; padding-right:120px;">
    <a style="color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; float:left">LOGO
     <a href="blog.html">Book A Trip</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn">Tours & Activity</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="rooms.html">About</a>
    <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/idfrnffnd/2ynju1ax/6/)

The problem is at Tours & Activity button.

Comment: Maybe those 2 examples can help: 1.  https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=317b860f-b561-409d-ab68-83f8a6dda031 2. https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=7f6d05e7-9289-42dc-b443-84321e38a6b7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the top position of the `.dropdown-content`, like

```
.dropdown-content {
    top: 35px;
}
```

But I give you a better approach, so the dropdown menu will be absolute to it's parent `.dropdown`

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
}

nav a {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 430;
  color: lightgrey;
}

nav a.active{
  color: #d4af37;
}

nav a:hover:not(.active){
  color: white;
}

nav.scroll {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 430;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <div style="padding-left:105px; padding-right:120px;">
    <a style="color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; float:left">LOGO</a>
    <a href="blog.html">Book A Trip</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn">Tours & Activity</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="rooms.html">About</a>
    <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Note my changes in your classes.

Answer (score 2):

**Copy the code to an HTML file to try links more effectively**

I converted the `<div>` containing the links into a drop-down list
&& i have made the necessary modifications in the css file from a to option
I set `<select>` to a drop down and always opened the number of links displayed `size = "3"`

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 4em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 24px;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
   }

   nav a {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 430;
    color: lightgrey;
   }
   
   nav a.active{
    color: #d4af37;
   }
   
   nav a:hover:not(.active){
    color: white;
   }
   
   nav.scroll {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
   }
   
   .dropdown {
     float: right;
     overflow: hidden;
   }

   .dropdown .dropbtn {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 430;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin: 0;
   }
   
   .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: lightgrey;
     min-width: 250px;
     z-index: 1;
   }

   .dropdown-content option {
     float: none;
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
   }

   .dropdown-content option:hover {
     color: #ddd;
   }

   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
   }
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
    <div style="padding-left:105px; padding-right:120px;">
    <a style="color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; float:left">LOGO</a>
    <a href="blog.html">Book A Trip</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropbtn">Tours &amp; Activity</a>
        <select class="dropdown-content" size="3" onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
          <option value="https://www.facebook.com">link 1</option>
          <option value="https://www.google.com">link 2</option>
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com">link 3</option>
         </select>
        </div>
    <a href="rooms.html">About</a>
    <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <a class="dropbtn">Tours & Activity</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#"><button>link 1</button ></a>
        <a href="#"><button>link 2</button ></a>
        <a href="#"><button>link 3</button ></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreate your project, using list elements for menu is better.

```css
body{
  margin:0
}

*{
  box-sizing:border-box
}

nav{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  background:black;
  padding:1.5rem 8rem;
}

nav .nav-logo{
  font-size:calc(1rem + .25rem);
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold
}

nav a{
  color:lightgrey;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:1rem
}

nav a.active{
  color:#d4af37
}

nav a:hover:not(.active){
  color:white
}

nav ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

nav ul:not(.dropdown-content){
  display:flex;
}


nav ul > li{
  margin-right:1rem
}

.dropdown{
  position:relative;
}

.dropdown-content{
  position:absolute;
  top:1.5rem;
  background:grey;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  transition:250ms
}

.dropdown a:hover ~ .dropdown-content, .dropdown-content:hover{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible
}



.dropdown-content li a{
  font-size:calc(1em - 1px);
  padding:.8rem;
  display:flex;
  min-width:10rem
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a href="#" class="nav-logo">LOGO</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Tours & Activity</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Book A Trip</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```